# Allow only the next 5 business days jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker which I am using to set appointments. The only problem with this is that the boss wants the appointment date to only be up to the next 5 business days. I know how to disable the weekends, but I am a little unclear as to how I can make it so that if I choose a wednesday, it lets me select a date up to the next wednesday and accounts for the weekends as well. Any one have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: This could help, it has a solved jsFiddle with exactly the same question as yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584701/jquery-ui-datepicker-restricted-selection-working-days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
$('yourSelector').datepicker({
    minDate: 0, // your min date
    maxDate: '+1w', // one week will always be 5 business day - not sure if you are including current day
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends // disable weekends
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wANFJ/

Comment: Beat me to it by 4 seconds :P

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I needed! Thanks for the help! I was unaware you could use almost a php strtotime type string. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

5 business days is the same as 1 full week, so please try to set the datepicker maxDate to "+1w" or "+5d".

Comment: Specially when you are new and trying to understand how to do things correctly :/

Comment: Late to the party, but it's because +1w or +5d would not give you business days as it'd include weekend days.

Answer (score -2):

Check out http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Can probably get away with

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: 5 });
```

EDIT: Missed the part about business days only, this obviously won't do that.

You can try the below snippet, might take into account your weekend settings.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ maxDate: '+1w' });
```