# Dynamically update a dropdown based on datepicker day of the week

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'd like to have a dropdown that gives the user the option to select certain times based on the day of the week selected.

Basically if someone selects a Monday, they can schedule a tour for 9:30, 10, 10:30, etc... but if they select a Tuesday they can have a tour at 2, 2:30 etc....

Is this possible with datepicker or should I use something else?

Comment: Have you looked at the datepicker `onSelect` function? http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

You could use the information from [jQuery ui datepicker, get Day of week from onSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237478/jquery-ui-datepicker-get-day-of-week-from-onselect) to get the day of the week `onSelect`, and change the options for time based on that.

Comment: I'm sorry, like I said I'm not a programmer. I just wrote a bunch of nonsense that, no surprise, isn't working.